# How to add multiple favicon to Nextjs 13 with generateMetaData() under app directory?

Tags: html, next.js, metadata, next.js13

I have a `next@13` application with the `app` directory. There are many articles about it but they are all about NextJS < 13.

I generate the metadata in `layout.tsx`. I have the following favicons:

`favicon-16x16.png`, `favicon-32x32.png`, `favicon-96x96.png`, `favicon-180x180.png`, `favicon-512x512.png` and svg versions as well.

How can I add all these to my website dynamically?

`src/app/[language]/layout.tsx`

```
export async function generateMetaData() {
  const translate = await getTranslations("home")

  return {
    title: translate("title"),
    description: translate("description"),
    icons: {
      icon: "/favicon.ico",
    },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[you can use generateMetadata to add dynamic meta data based on i.e. routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata)